# Toggle CSS class on vote

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery handled buttons. But I think I overdid it with the `if else` statements.

I am wondering if the code can be more efficient in some way than what I have. It's mainly voting up and down. So what is does is toggle buttons and inserts HTML.

```
function handleVote(commentid, voted, type){
    $.ajax({
      url: endpoint + commentid + "/update/",
      method: "PATCH",
      data: { commentid: commentid, voted: voted,  type: type},
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
        if(type === 'down' && voted === 'True'){
          $('.comment-item .down-vote .i-down-'+commentid+'').toggleClass('active-color');
          $('.comment-item .down-vote .i-down-'+commentid+'').toggleClass('opacity-initial');
          $('.comment-item .down-vote .i-down-'+commentid+'').css('opacity', '0.2')
        } else if(type === 'down' && voted === 'False'){
          $('.comment-item .down-vote .i-down-'+commentid+'').toggleClass('active-color');
          $('.comment-item .down-vote .i-down-'+commentid+'').toggleClass('opacity-initial');
        } else if(type === 'up' && voted === 'True'){
          $('.comment-item .up-vote .i-up-'+commentid+'').toggleClass('primary-color');
          $('.comment-item .up-vote .i-up-'+commentid+'').toggleClass('opacity-initial');
          $('.comment-item .up-vote .i-up-'+commentid+'').css('opacity', '0.2')
        } else if(type === 'up' && voted === 'False'){
          $('.comment-item .down-vote .i-up-'+commentid+'').toggleClass('primary-color');
          $('.comment-item .down-vote .i-up-'+commentid+'').toggleClass('opacity-initial');
        }

        $(".comment-vote-down .vote-count-down-" + commentid +"").html(`-${data.num_vote_down}`);
        $(".comment-vote-up .vote-count-up-" + commentid +"").html(`+${data.num_vote_up}`);
      },
      error: function(data){
        var msg = formatErrorMsg(data.responseJSON)
        $("[data-id='" + commentid + "']").closest('div .comment-wrapper').after(msg);
      }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use variable for element, toggle can take multiple classes, use minimal selector.

```
var voteButton;
if(type === 'down'){
    voteButton = $('.i-down-' + commentid);
    voteButton.toggleClass('active-color opacity-initial');
} else {
    voteButton = $('.i-up-'+commentid);
    voteButton.toggleClass('primary-color opacity-initial');    
}
if(voted === 'True'){
    voteButton.css('opacity', '0.2')
}
```

or you could stack functions

```
$('.comment-item .down-vote .i-down-'+commentid+'')
  .toggleClass('active-color opacity-initial')
  .css('opacity', '0.2')
```

Comment: If you're able to use ES6 syntax, or transpile with Babel, you can also use string literals to make the selector dynamic, e.g. `\`.comment-item .${type}-vote .i-${type}-${commentid}\``